# Jmeter - CSV Data Set Config reaching <EOF>, reading values only for alternate threads

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am facing a wierd issue with CSV Data Set Config. I get values for alternate threads and alternate threads it is fetching `<EOF>` values.

I have shared the test script with all the related files --> [JMeterScript.zip] : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48816404/JMeterScript.zip

**Expected result** : 
`Thread 1 : username = p_user1, password = p_pass1, WAIT0 = 1200<br>
Thread 1 : var1 = value1, var2 = value2, var3 = value3, var4 = value4, var5 = value5, var6 = value6<br>
Thread 3 : username = p_user2, password = p_pass2, WAIT0 = 117000<br>
Thread 3 : var1 = value11, var2 = value12, var3 = value13, var4 = value14, var5 = value15, var6 = value16<br>
Thread 5 : username = p_user3, password = p_pass3, WAIT0 = 114000<br>
Thread 5 : var1 = value21, var2 = value22, var3 = value23, var4 = value24, var5 = value25, var6 = value26<br>
Thread 7 : username = p_user4, password = p_pass4, WAIT0 = 111000<br>
Thread 7 : var1 = value31, var2 = value32, var3 = value33, var4 = value34, var5 = value35, var6 = value36<br>
....`

**Result I am getting** :
`Thread 1 : username = p_user1, password = p_pass1, WAIT0 = 1200
Thread 1 : var1 = <EOF>, var2 = <EOF>, var3 = <EOF>, var4 = <EOF>, var5 = <EOF>, var6 = <EOF>
Thread 2 : username = , password = ${password}, WAIT0 = ${WAIT0}
Thread 2 : var1 = value1, var2 = value2, var3 = value3, var4 = value4, var5 = value5, var6 = value6
Thread 3 : username = p_user2, password = p_pass2, WAIT0 = 117000
Thread 3 : var1 = <EOF>, var2 = <EOF>, var3 = <EOF>, var4 = <EOF>, var5 = <EOF>, var6 = <EOF>
Thread 4 : username = , password = ${password}, WAIT0 = ${WAIT0}
Thread 4 : var1 = value11, var2 = value12, var3 = value13, var4 = value14, var5 = value15, var6 = value16
....`

I am using Java 7u51 and JMeter 2.10.

Please let me know, if any other details are needed.

Any inputs/suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
Sajid

P.S. Posting a question for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check JMeter.log to see if you don't have a FileNotFoundException which means your file was not found.
Where do you put your CSVs when you run ?

What are your startup arguments for JMeter ?

Also your CSV are strange regarding line break and first character.

Comment: The issue was extra Line Feed characters which got introduced due to inter_op settings in my clearcase view. Unfortunately, it did not show up in TextPad. Fortunately, it showed up in clearcase diff when compared with a working version of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this `EOF` issue in `CSV` config and found that it was showing error of file not found. I have put the `CSV` file in bin and `jmeter` was searching it on desktop. So it was showing `EOF` to me. Try this.
For avoiding this, use `Stop Thread` on `EOF = True` in `CSV` config element.